# Running RAILS_ENV=production with the system command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, nginx, centos

I have got a really weird problem with a script that I am running on my server, the details are below. But essentially I am using a script to set up a rails application and I am calling that script from an existing rails application.

In my existing application (the application that is calling the script on the server) I have:-

```
Spawnling.new do
   system "cd ~/ && ~/*/create_site.sh param1 param2 >> /tmp/logger"
end
```

The create_site.sh script creates a fresh installation of rails using the below:

```
rails new $DIR --database postgresql
```

It then does a number of things to set up the application. The issue is that the script seems to run absolutely fine until it gets to the following command:

```
cd $DIR && RAILS_ENV=production rails g roroacms:install -v && RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean && RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

It is really odd because when I run the top command manually as the root user it seems to run absolutely fine without any issues at all. When I view the logger file at the end of the top command it looks like the below:

```
Your bundle is updated!
Bundle is installed and up to date
RoroaCMS installation
Installation complete with assets
Server started
```

When I run this manually it outputs a number of messages between each line where it is running the command. Any ideas on this? I am thinking that it could be something to do with RAILS_ENV as the rails new command runs fine earlier in the script.

Comment: are you running the script as root?

Comment: Well when I run it manually as root, it works correctly but when I run the command in a cron or in the above command it fails at the rails g roroacms:install I think it might be something to do with that but there is no error message so it is really hard to debug

Answer (score 0):

Hi I do a fair bit of scripting rails on servers and I always use the format `bundle exec rails g rspec:install production` so your command would be `cd $DIR && bundle exec rails g roroacms:install -v production && bundle exec rake assets:clean production && bundle exec rake assets:precompile production`. I dont have a whole lot of reasoning behind it but that format seems to be most reliable across different server environments.